# Grails scheduling a task without plugins

Tags: grails, scheduled-tasks, grails-2.0

For one of our applications we have a different Tasks that we would like to happen on a scheduled basis.  However we don't want to bother with quartz for several different reasons.

In grails, how do we go about scheduling a task that can run on a regular basis?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After researching for quite some time we came to this conclusion:

Within the Groovy Source Packages we created an interface

```
interface Task{
  void executeTask()
}
```

Next we created our Task:

```
class SayHelloTask implements Task{
    void executeTask(){
    println "Hello"
  }
}
```

Within the `resources.groovy` file we added the following:

```
import package.SayHelloTask
beans = {
  sayHelloTask(SayHelloTask){
  }

  xmlns task: "http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"

  task.'scheduled-tasks'{
    task.scheduled(ref:'retryEmailTask', method: 'executeTask', cron: '0-59 * * * * *')
  }
}
```

We went with this solution because it cut the overhead of Quartz.  It matches how we do things in our Java projects.

Comment: Instead of adding a Task, the scheduled task could be a method in any bean! E.g. task.scheduled(ref:'beanA', method: 'methodB', cron: '0 0/30 * * * *')

Answer (score 5):

I prefer using the annotations on my services when dealing with Spring based scheduled tasks.

**grails-app/conf/spring/resrouces.groovy**

```
beans {
    xmlns task: "http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    task.'annotation-driven'('proxy-target-class': true)
}
```

Then on my service:

```
class MyService {
  @Scheduled(cron="*/5 * * * * MON-FRI")
  void doSomething() {
    ...    
  }
}
```

Regardless of how you do this, be cautious about your Hibernate session scope. Good luck!

Comment: Could you add a bit more about the Hibernate session scope? What do we need to be looking for?

Comment: Consider the fact you are creating a new thread managed by the TaskScheduler in Spring. Which by default doesn't have a hibernate session associated with it because it's not going through Grails to set one up. You will need to DomainClass.withNewSession or something similar to get a hibernate session. You could always look at the source code for the Quartz plugin and see how it handles it or look at the Executor plugin: http://www.grails.org/plugin/executor

Comment: I agree this should work in theory, but there's an open bug for this exact case not working: https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-8921. I think it only applies to annotations though. I've had success scheduling tasks with just the xml namespace without annotations.

Comment: Is there a way to kick off this service outside of it's schedule, for testing ?

Answer (score 5):

For the records, as of Grails 3.2.10 this can be achieved neatly by using annotations the following way.

Create an ordinary Grails service:

```
class ScheduledService {
  boolean lazyInit = false    // <--- this is important

  @Scheduled(fixedRate = 20000L)
  def myBusinessMethodForTheJob() {
    log.info 'Executing scheduled job...'
  }
}
```

Enable scheduling in the application:

```
@EnableScheduling
class Application extends GrailsAutoConfiguration {
    static void main(String[] args) {
        GrailsApp.run(Application, args)
    }
}
```

Done.

Comment: Thanks for the update!  While I have not done Grails in 3+ years It should be helpful for someone!

Answer (score 2):

Another option is the `Timer` and `TimerTask` classes provided by the JDK. You can run this example in the Groovy console to see it in action

```
def task = new TimerTask() {

  void run() {
    println "task running at ${new Date()}"
  }
}

def firstExecutionDelay = 1000
def delayBetweenExecutions = 2000

new Timer(true).schedule(task, firstExecutionDelay, delayBetweenExecutions)
```

Comment: Not quite what I was looking for but I will keep this in mind for later projects.  Plus it will be good for people that want to do the same thing later :-)